# Google Groups PHP API Get existing Group

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-groups-api

Using Groups PHP API and trying to get existing group settings and members.

Thanks to help from divideandconquer.se, I have modified my code:

```
function get_google_group($groupId) {
    $group = false;
    try {
        echo '<br />Getting Google Group: ' . $groupId . '<br />';
        $myClient = $this->getClient();
        $myClient->addScope( 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings');
        $groupsettingsService = new Google_Service_Groupssettings($myClient);
        $group = $groupsettingsService->groups->get($groupId);

        echo 'SUCCESS: group=';

    } catch (exception $e) {
        echo '<br />*** EXCEPTION *** ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
        return false;
    }

    return $group;
}
```

I am still getting an exception:on the call to the 'get' method:

```
Getting Google Group: 04k668n33tdjvkw

*** EXCEPTION *** Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/04k668n33tdjvkw: (403) GData insufficientPermissions Insufficient Permission
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Google_Service_Groupssettings_Groups_Resource` directly. Use `Google_Service_Groupssettings`, like this:

```
 $myClient->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings');
 $groupsettingsService = new Google_Service_Groupssettings($myClient);
 $group = $groupsettingsService->groups->get($groupId);
```

Comment: Thank you! that certainly helped. Now I get Error calling GET :insufficientPermissions, but I think I can work with this for the moment.

Comment: Updated my response to eventually fix the insufficient permissions.

Comment: Had to add a 'new' in front of Google_Service_Groupssettings($myClient), but code still failing with permissions problem. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Interestingly, I can create a new group and add/remove members using the permissions I have, but cannot read (get) existing groups.